# How can I perform the click event on a Progress spinner?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, mouseevent

I want the progress spinner to work like a button. I added a `click` event handler on the progress spinner, but when I am clicking on gif image of spinner it is not performing the click event. 
I use the below code:

![see the screen shot][1]

```
public ExamMarks()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // make the clicks on the picturebox invoke the click event
        // on our control
        Loading_pb.Click += (o, e) => { this.OnClick(e); };
    }
    public bool IsStart = false;
    [Description("Load Image .gif in the object"), Category("Data")]
    public Image LoadGIFImage
    {
        get { return Loading_pb.Image; }
        set { Loading_pb.Image = value; }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        IsStart = true;
        this.Visible = true;
        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Loading);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        IsStart = false;
        this.Visible = false;
    }
    void Loading(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (IsStart)
        {
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you forget to add an event handler and only added the code part?

Comment: How do you register the event with the spinner?

Comment: Which control is that? on the screenshot it reads `CNSpinn...`, which doesn't look like a standard winforms control

Comment: @Peroxy it shows in the designer screenshot, so it's reasonably safe to assume it is indeed added to the event

Comment: I added CNSpinner.dll reference and tool for this spinner. and I generated click event from the events of this spinner tool.

Comment: With the code you posted, we can only assume your txtRoll has text, and your comboBoxes have something selected greater than index zero.  What are we supposed to focus on to help you?

Comment: @LarsTech the given code is just to show the click event of spinner. Don't look deeply inside the code. Main thing is that the click event of this spinner control is not working. I want to use spinner as a button. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the additional information in the comments, I'm assumming you are using `CNSpinner.dll` from [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1004624/Gif-viewer-Snipper-control).

The problem is that the control is a `UserControl` with a `PictureBox` that covers it completely. So even if you are assigning the `Click` event handler to the control, the actual control receiving the clicks is the `PictureBox` contained into the control.

You can modify the `CNSpinner` code and just make a `Click` event on the `PictureBox` that invokes the `Click` event on the actual control, but without modifying the `CNSpinner` control, your event will never be called. That's a limitation on the implementation of the control as you are using it.

If you want to modify the original `CNSpinner`, an easy way (not the only one, nor the best one) would be something like (on `ProgressSpinner.cs`):

```
public ProgressSpinner()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   // make the clicks on the picturebox invoke the click event
   // on our control
   Loading_pb.Click += (o,e) => { this.OnClick(e); }
}
```

Comment: Sir, actually I wanted to show an animated gif picture as a button on my form so I am using the spinner control to show the animated pic on the form. Please can you share the another method to show the gif pic on the win form instead of using progress spinner.

Comment: @PrashantArora that progress spinner is not "all that bad" (although the implementation could be way better, but ok). It's just a `BackgroundWorker` forcing the refresh of a `PictureBox` control. You could either do that yourself, or just add the modification I gave on the same `CNSpinner` you are using (you'll need to download the sourcecode and compile it yourself, but shouldn't be that hard)

Comment: sorry sir, the click event is still not working. Please see above I edited the question to show the code which I applied given by you.

Comment: I haven't really tested any of this. In theory, it should work. I'm on my phone now, but will do a test project as soon as I'm on the computer with some free 10 minutes and see if I've missed something

Comment: @PrashantArora I made a very simple project, and with my addition to `ProgressSpinner`, it works fine, and my click event is raised